# Django_filters Filtering Dates not working

Tags: django, django-filters

I'm creating a filter using django_filters. I want to filter for a date range but it's not working. My filter ignores my `start_date` and my `end_date`.

Here's my filters.py:

```
class ArticleFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    date_range = django_filters.DateRangeFilter(field_name='pub_date')

    start_date = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name="pub_date", lookup_expr="gt", widget=widgets.DateInput(attrs={"class": "datepicker"}))
    end_date = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name="pub_date", lookup_expr="lt", widget=widgets.DateInput(attrs={"class": "datepicker"}))

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ["Category", "start_date", "end_date"]
        ordering = ["-pub_date"]
```

btw. `pub_date` is a `DateTime`object.

Comment: what do you mean 'My filter ignores my start_date and my end_date'? What is the `Meta` of your filter?

Comment: @robtus88 When I select a date my filter doesn't use it. It gets ignored. Added Meta to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just want to have a `DateFilter` and not a `DateTimeFilter` since you use a `DateInput` widget, so here is it:

```
start_date = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name="pub_date", lookup_expr="gt", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "datepicker"}))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not working. I add a date to my `TextInput` but I still get articles with any dates.

Comment: what is the url generated when the filter form is submitted? do you use `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS` in your settings?

Comment: My url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/artikel/?start_date=02%2F01%2F2019&end_date=02%2F01%2F2019`  and my DATE_INPUT_FORMATS: `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ("%m/%d/%Y", )`